# Autodesk forge Viewer - C# - Get Properties from Revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are implementing the Autodesk Forge Viewer in our web application.
While uploading the Revit file - we are creating bucket, token, and translate the file to SVF using C# code.
After that, we have called the below Model derivative API to get the properties details. If we call the below API it returns only `result:Success` but does not return the properties.
Please help to resolve to get all properties along with Success results.
Below is the code for your reference.

`string requestURL1 = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/" + objectIdBase64 + "/metadata" + Guid + "/properties";`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you forge to include **/properties** within your endpoint? It should return you all the properties for this endpoint according to my test just now..

Comment: It will take you some time to wait for Forge service to read your model properties data while calling `GET Properties endpoint` for the first time. After a while, you should get the properties data as expected after calling `GET Properties endpoint` again. Could you have a try?